# Bootstrap SASS result

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I use Bootstrap 3.3.5 with SASS. But the CSS final's file is strange.

I write that :

```
section.strat-01 {
    @include make-row();

    .strat-01-img {
        @include make-xs-column(12);
        @include make-sm-column-offset(1);
        @include make-sm-column(4);
        @include make-sm-column-pull(6);    
    }

    .strat-01-txt {
        @include make-xs-column(12);
        @include make-sm-column(6);
        @include make-sm-column-push(5);
    }
}
```

And I have that, double properties :

```
section.strat-01 .strat-01-img {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 1px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-right: 15px;
            position: relative;
            min-height: 1px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-right: 15px; 
}
```

What's wrong ? Why the double properties are not combined ?

Comment: What result were you expecting?

Comment: A code without double properties. For example I have twice "position". The result is strange no ?

Comment: Why would you expect that when when the code you wrote explicitly declares double properties?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated properties from several mixins never combine together...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So how can I avoid double properties ?

Comment: Shouldn't your code generate CSS for media queries?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want to do here is just split this up into multiple media queries as mentioned in the comments.

The reason your output CSS seems 'dumb' is because SASS is only a pre compiler, whatever you put into it comes out and thus using multiple mixins in the same selector are simply giving you back all their values.

The reason CSS doesn't filter this is because it will simply overwrite or extend rules / selectors defined earlier which is how CSS works (Cascading Style Sheets)

Either way you don't have a lot of work to do to make it work, all you'll want for the correct CSS to be applied at the correct resolution is to split it in media queries e.g.

```
$my-sm-res: 768px //for instance
$my-xs-res: 480px //for instance

@media (max-width: $my-sm-res)
    .section.strat-01
        .strat-01-img
            @include make-sm-column-offset(...)
            @include make-sm-column(...)
            @include make-sm-column-pull(...)

@media (max-width: $my-xs-res)
    .section.strat-01
        .strat-01-img
            @include make-xs-column-offset(...)
            @include make-xs-column(...)
            @include make-xs-column-pull(...)
```

This example here is what will give you the **xs** styling when your screen has a resulution of *480px* or less and will give you the **md** styling for when your screen has a resolution of *768px* or less.

Hope it helps, GL!

#### EDIT

I'm using the SASS format here which is technically not valid CSS (nor is SCSS really but if you pull out the sassy bits you'll be left with *valid* CSS instead of SASS that you still have to change.)

For the example to work in your situation all you'd need to do is add the missing `{}` pairs and add `;` semicolons at the end of each `prop: val` pair.

[More on SASS vs SCSS](http://thesassway.com/editorial/sass-vs-scss-which-syntax-is-better) (for those interested)

[Some basics on CSS (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/How_CSS_works)